# XLabels overlay each other in achartengite in Android 4.3

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a problem with overlay of x labels in achartengine TimeChart with time format => `chart.setDateFormat("kk:mm:ss")`.

If I test in in Android 4.0.4 (Samsung galaxy tab) the x labels are visible in a way that they don't overlay each other.

But the problem is in Android 4.3 (HTC One - Full HD), where it seems that this filtering is not working, so there are too much of labels and they overlay each other and user can not read anything. It seems that it happens also in Y axis where the values are doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

So I found the solution. The problem was, that I'm using achartengine as an library project and I was building achartengine project in API 10, and my app was in API 14.

Because of that I had some strange behavior. When I changed achartengine project library to be build in API 14, the problem disappeared.

:)